Dobbiamo preoccuparci della scarsità di domande?
Quali soluzioni potrebbero proporsi per risolvere il problema della scarsità di domande?
Potremmo concludere, per esempio, che i membri della community non hanno da chiedere alcunché? 
Certo, per ora siamo in 'private beta', per cui è difficile proporre considerazioni generali, ma, forse, iniziare a comprendere le strategie del futuro, quelle che possano rendere IL&U interessante, è utile sin da ora.
Quindi, cosa dovremmo fare?

cosa dovremmo fare? Ad esempio, accettare le risposte? Kyriakos, con tutto il rispetto, 21 domande senza scegliere mai una risposta non danno un buon esempio, sopratutto per gli utenti nuovi.

@I.M., ma siamo ancora in beta privata! Non credi sia il caso di attendere che nuovi e futuri utenti possano cimentarsi con maggiore motivazione nel rispondere alle domande prive di risposte accettate?

Non credo. Completamente prive di risposte, magari. A) Chi andrà a cercare quelle domande in fondo del sito dopo 2-6 mesi quando la beta sarà pubblica? B) Chi risponderà alle domande "vecchie", conoscendo che quella risposta sicuramente non sarà molto votata e per di più che neanche l'OP accetta risposte alle sue domande? Prego di scusarmi, ma di quale motivazione parliamo? C) Penso anche delle domande duplicate: The original question must have an answer; you cannot mark a question as a duplicate of an unanswered one

@I.M., have you read Abby's post? It seems we don't have to wait 2-6 months to have IL(&U) in public beta, but only a week.

Yes, I saw it. Well, I wouldn't like to seem too insisting, just express some thoughts. Yet, I believe you know what you do.

È presto per preoccuparsene, secondo me.
Al momento la stragrande maggioranza di utenti sono madrelingua, quindi è normale che abbiano più risposte che domande da fornire. Quando la beta sarà pubblica inizieranno ad affluire molti più utenti non madrelingua e ci saranno conseguentemente più domande.
Se questo non accadrà, ce ne preoccuperemo a tempo debito.

I am slightly worried because, whilst I agree that once we are public we will get more non-mother-tongue questions, I do think that we should see a few, maybe tougher questions asked by the current mother-tongue users.
In other words, I would have expected Italians to ask for more "advanced" questions, which they clearly aren't doing.
However, this basically will only affect the level of the site and not its overall health, in the long run - in my opinion.

What do you mean by "more advanced questions"? Clearly, if most of the beta users are native speakers of Italian, some aspects of the language are not noticed, since we are all used to them. People who doen't speak Italian as first language could notice some patterns, and could ask about them. We need those people, to have more "advanced" questions.

@kiamlaluno Sicuramente esiste un livello "accademico" di studio della lingua Italiana. Non abbiamo domande a quel livello.

Sure, there are academic questions, but I would expect them to be asked by academics, which I also expect to know the answer in most of the cases. I hope we don't become like EL&U, which first was thought to be for advanced English, but now accepts also questions about the meaning of a sentence found in a newspaper.

Visto che siamo ancora in beta privata, è normale non avere molte domande. Da parte mia, ho fatto domande che potrebbero interessare persone che parlano inglese come prima lingua e che potrebbero essere confusi da alcuni aspetti dell'italiano, oltre ad alcune domande a cui ero personalmente interessato e che potrebbero servire ad altri utenti.
Anche se dovesse succedere durante la beta pubblica, non ci sarebbe niente da preoccuparsi, visto che ci sono siti in beta pubblica da mesi e mesi, se non addirittura un anno e passa. Ci sono siti che, visto l'argomento, hanno una ristretta cerchia di interessati; penso che siamo fortunati, visto che ci sono molte persone nate fuori dall'Italia, ma con radici italiane che potrebbero essere interessate ad usare il sito.
Per nostra fortuna, questo è l'unico sito dedicato all'italiano, contrariamente all'inglese che ha due siti: "English Language and Usage" and "English Language Learners". Per lo meno non ci saranno problemi con persone che non sanno in che sito scrivere la loro domanda, visto che non ci sono siti che sono "competitori".
